# Same contact form for all sites in Wordpress Multisite network?

Tags: wordpress

So, what I have:
Wordpress => Multisite (MU domain, different domains) => Contact Form 7 (or any other plugin)

Shortcode [contact form] in blog #1 (where contact form was created) - it works fine.

Shortcode [contact form] in blog #2 (with switch in php to blog #1) - contact form seen, but it doesnt send (infinite loading after pressing button).

As I understand - problem is plugin when called from domain where form didnt created - understand that and doesnt work.

How I can use same contact form (from any plugin) for all WP Multisite Network?

Answer (score 0):

You could use online form for multisite, for example http://www.jotform.com/

Comment: When I have my contact form:
1) it's free;
2) I have 60 sites in network, for each site - own manager, and for each contact form (on each site) I put by js their email to reciever of contact form so they recieve feedback directly. Problem is now we have 60 different contact forms (I mean they same, but 60 times in database and control for each - crazy):
3) WPML, we have 3 languages on all sites, it's kind of problem to use online forms with our needs.